# Classes not found while upgrading GXT 2.3.1a to 4.1.0

Tags: extjs, upgrade, gxt

While upgrading GXT from 2.3.1a to 4.1.0,

Following classes are not found in gxt-4.1.0 jar

com.extjs.gxt.ui.client.data.PagingLoadResult
com.extjs.gxt.ui.client.data.BasePagingLoadConfig

Are there any alternatives for these classes ?

Tried looking into migration document from sencha, but haven't found anything.
Looking for alternative for these classes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

GXT 2's `com.extjs.gxt.ui.client.data.PagingLoadResult` is now `com.sencha.gxt.data.shared.loader.PagingLoadResult`.

`com.extjs.gxt.ui.client.data.BasePagingLoadConfig` is probably best replaced by `com.sencha.gxt.data.shared.loader.PagingLoadConfigBean`.

For more information, check out their [GXT 2->3/4 migration guide](https://docs.sencha.com/gxt/4.x/guides/data/DataProxy.html) and [javadoc for the `shared.loader` packages](https://docs.sencha.com/gxt/4.x/javadoc/gxt-4.0.2/com/sencha/gxt/data/shared/loader/package-tree.html).